# ScrollingToolbarLayout no "up" button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm setting up a collapsible `Toolbar`, and for some reason the up button in the toolbar is invisible.

I know it's invisible not non-existent, because I can still interact with it and go back to the main activity. Note that I'm running the app on Marshmallow.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="nz.zephire.zinema.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimary">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/backdrop_description"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >


                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/detail_poster"
                        android:src="@drawable/poster_no_image"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/poster_description"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Description Placeholder\n\n\n"
                        android:id="@+id/detail_overview"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="PLACEHOLDER\n\n\nDETAILS\n\n\n"/>
                    <!-- TODO: Details-->

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I should add that I use `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar); getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` As well, which creates the button in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with the layout file I finally worked out the solution to the problem - the background for the collapsible toolbar was above the toobar's back button.

This was a simple fix. Move the `ImageView` above the `Toolbar` and it works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying something like this:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_18dp));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //launch main activity or handle back button press event
        }
    });
```

You can find the icon ic_arrow_back_white_18dp icon [here](https://design.google.com/icons/). You just need to type in `back` in the search bar.

Comment: Just gave that a shot - added it below where I initialize the toolbar as an ActionBar.

Doesn't seem to work - still can't see an arrow, but can still click it as usual.

Comment: Did you download the arrow image? Also, can you look for anything unusual in logcat and post it here in case you find it? It might not be an appcompat v7 toolbar as well.

Comment: This is the verbose logcat from when the activity is launched: http://pastebin.com/kUehDq4D

As for the arrow - yes I downloaded and saved to drawables. From the xml you can see as well that it's is definitely an appcompat toolbar rather than a standard toolbar.